# How To Make Abstract Class And Inherit In Other Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**I have two clsses with similar code in both but having different variables**

***ISource.cs***

```
public interface ISource
{
    string AvailConfigPath { get; }

    string AvailVersion { get; }

    IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles { get; }
}

public class Source : ISource
{
    public string AvailConfigPath
    {
        get
        {
            return @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Source\AvailInfoFile.config";
        }
    }

    private XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Source\AvailInfoFile.config");

    public string AvailVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                         .Element("InfoConfigFile")
                         .Attribute("version").Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                         .Element("files")
                         .Elements("file")
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                       x => x.Attribute("version").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

***ITarget.cs***

```
   public interface ITarget
{
    string LocalConfigPath { get; }

    string LocalVersion { get; }

    IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles { get; }
}

internal class Target : ITarget
{
    public string LocalConfigPath
    {
        get
        {
            return @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Target\LocalInfoFile.config";
        }
    }

    private XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Target\LocalInfoFile.config");

    public string LocalVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("InfoConfigFile")
                     .Attribute("version").Value;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("files")
                     .Elements("file")
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   x => x.Attribute("version").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now i want to make an abstract class and put my common code in that class file and then inherite  that code in these both class files**

Comment: Okay, so what's stopping you?

Comment: I want a million dollars

Comment: Write the abstract class with the virtual definitions and override them in the derived classes. Not sure where's the difficulty

Comment: i think he is confused about his design, it doesnt feel right, and not sure. but also he cant clearly explain what he wants to do.

Comment: DarthVadar exclaiming it doesn't feel right. There is an imbalance in the force it seems ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to combine them this way:

```
public interface ITarget
{
    string LocalConfigPath { get; }
    string LocalVersion { get; }
    IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles { get; }
}

public interface ISource
{
    string AvailConfigPath { get; }
    string AvailVersion { get; }
    IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles { get; }
}

internal abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string ConfigPath { get; }
    private XDocument document = XDocument.Load(ConfigPath);

    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("InfoConfigFile")
                     .Attribute("version").Value;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Files
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("files")
                     .Elements("file")
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   x => x.Attribute("version").Value);
        }
    }
}

internal class Target : BaseClass, ITarget
{
    public override string LocalConfigPath
    {
        get
        {
            return @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Target\LocalInfoFile.config";
        }
    }

    public string LocalVersion
    {
        get { return Version; }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles
    {
        get { return Files; }
    }
}

public class Source : BaseClass, ISource
{
    public override string AvailConfigPath
    {
        get
        { return @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Source\AvailInfoFile.config"; }
    }

    public string AvailVersion
    {
        get { return Version; }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles
    {
        get { return Files; }
    }
}
```

Note: Do not use the class name `BaseClass` - make it something more domain-appropriate.  I was just using it to illustrate that is was the "base class"

Also note that if `Source` is public then `BaseClass` has to be public as well.  If you *really* want to bake *BaseClass* internal then you could use encapsulation instead of inheritance - which is still re-using code but the plumbing is different.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks To D Stanley__ your answer helped me a lot to solve this problem**

**AbstractClass.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{

    private string _ConfigPath;

    public string ConfigPath
    {
        get { return _ConfigPath; }
        set { _ConfigPath = value; }
    }


    private XDocument _Document = null;

    private XDocument document
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Document == null)
                _Document = XDocument.Load(ConfigPath);

            return _Document;
        }
    }

    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("InfoConfigFile")
                     .Attribute("version").Value;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Files
    {
        get
        {
            return document.Root
                     .Element("files")
                     .Elements("file")
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   x => x.Attribute("version").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

***ISource.cs***

```
 public interface ISource
{
    string ConfigPath { get; }

    string AvailVersion { get; }

    IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles { get; }
}
public class Source : BaseClass, ISource
{
    public Source()
    {
        ConfigPath = @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Source\AvailInfoFile.config";
    }


    public string AvailVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return Version;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> AvailFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return Files;
        }
    }
}
```

***ITarget.cs***

```
public interface ITarget
{
    string ConfigPath { get; }

    string LocalVersion { get; }

    IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles { get; }
}

internal class Target : BaseClass, ITarget
{
    public Target()
    {
        ConfigPath = @"D:\Mindful\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AutoUpdator\AutoUpdator\Target\LocalInfoFile.config";
    }
    public string LocalVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return Version;
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> LocalFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return Files;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If DStanley helped you, why does he not have the accepted answer? We don't need to see the end result anyway in that case, IMO.